# 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable' during running of opencv/kivy/python code

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, kivy

Okay for last 2 weeks or so I have been teaching myself both opencv and kivy in order to create a UI/Camera System for Autonomous mission from MATE ROV. (I don't feel like explaining about MATE ROV just google it) I have succeeded in creating both the UI and the camera implementation. However, whenever I go to add the `cv2.HoughLinesP` calculation to find the length of a rectangle in my test image.
[Test Image][1]
I get created by the code running for a short amount of time (usually runs through entire code a couple of times) then I get this.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 87, in <module>
     CamApp().run()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "main.py", line 56, in update
     for line in buf8:
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I have no clue what is causing this error so if anyone can help me out that would be great. Full Code is below.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

import cv2
import numpy as np

class CamApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.img0 = Image()
        self.img1 = Image()
        self.img2 = Image()
        self.img3 = Image()

        layout = GridLayout(cols = 4, rows = 3)

        layout.add_widget(self.img0)
        layout.add_widget(self.img1)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(self.img2)
        layout.add_widget(self.img3)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="HELP"))

        #opencv2 stuffs
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/33.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        # display image from cam in opencv window
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        # Flip Image and set up first frame
        buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, -1)

        # Convert main frame to Grayscale
        buf3 = cv2.cvtColor(buf1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Take Grayscale and add an adaptiveThreshold
        buf5 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(buf3,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

        # Edge detection and line detection
        buf7 = cv2.Canny(buf3,80,240,3)
        buf8 = cv2.HoughLinesP(buf7, 1, np.pi/180, 60, np.array([]), 50, 5)
        for line in buf8:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                cv2.line(buf8, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 4)
                distance_pixels = np.sqrt(np.square(x2 - x1) + np.square(y2 - y1))
                print(distance_pixels)

        # Necessary to display all the transformations and other bullshit
        buf0 = buf1.tostring()
        buf2 = buf3.tostring()
        buf4 = buf5.tostring()
        buf6 = buf7.tostring()

        # The next 9 lines are kivy bullshit to get the images on the screen.
        texture0 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='luminance')
        texture2 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='luminance')
        texture3 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='luminance')

        texture0.blit_buffer(buf0, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture1.blit_buffer(buf2, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture2.blit_buffer(buf4, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture3.blit_buffer(buf6, colorfmt='luminance', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        # display image from the texture
        self.img0.texture = texture0
        self.img1.texture = texture1
        self.img2.texture = texture2
        self.img3.texture = texture3

# Here's the running shit.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error is arising because in some case, no line is found by HoughLinesP() function thus "buf8" have value "None" at those instances.

Add a line before starting the for loop to check if "buf8" is "None" or not. If not None process, else break the process.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot. Thank you for your quick response